# How to add extra info to copied web text [Beginning and End]

Tags: javascript, html

Following javascript is used to append a link at the end of the copied text. I want to add the link in the beginning of the text, not at the bottom. How can I  do it?

EDIT: Got the answer for the above question, now i would like to know how to add it in the beginning and end at the same time.  Also would like to know how to add it in the middle of the copied text.

```
function addLink() {
        //Get the selected text and append the extra info
        var selection = window.getSelection(),
            pagelink = '<br /><br /> Read more at: ' + document.location.href,
            copytext = selection + pagelink,
            newdiv = document.createElement('div');

        //hide the newly created container
        newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

        //insert the container, fill it with the extended text, and define the new selection
        document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
        newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
        selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.removeChild(newdiv);
        }, 100);
    }

    document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```

Comment: Um.. did you try reversing the order? Like `copytext = pagelink + selection`?

Comment: I didn't. I'll try now

Comment: Thanks. It's working. BTW do you have any idea how to  add it in the middle of the copied text?

Comment: Editing the question. I would like to know how to add it in the beginning and end at the same time, also in the middle